# Salt Returners Returning to Master

Tags: saltstack

I have several servers setup with salt, I've been using the sqlite3 returner to record all my actions.  This work fine, but rows only get inserted on each minions local database.  How can I accumulate all of these records on the master?

Answer (score 1):

The Salt Master's job cache does this for you already.

```
salt-run jobs.list_jobs
```